# Hot folder - How to check the status of ingested files into Hybris?

Tags: dashboard, sap-commerce-cloud, commerce, hotfolder

In our current production system, we have several files that will be processed by Hybris hotfolder from external system on a daily / hourly basis. What is the best way to check the status of each file that is being processed by hot folder? Is there any OOTB dashboard functionality available for hotfolder? or is it a custom development?

So far, I'm following to check see backoffice cronjob logs. But it is very cumbersome process - by monitoring logs, finding out unique cron job id etc.. Any other best approaches?

I'm looking something similar to jenkins jobs status.
Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Why check cronjobs?
Hot-folder works on a polling basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround. Please check this link : 
https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1808/en-US/b8004ccfcbc048faa9558ae40ea7b188.html?q=CronJobProgressTracker

Firstly, you need to implement the CronJobProgressTracker class to your current cronjob. And you can see the progress of cronjob in either hac or Backoffice ;

> hac : execute flexible search
>
> Backoffice :  you can add a setting for the CronJobHistory menu. Then
>   just click the refresh button to see the last state of progress.

As I know , not possible to track file progress state in OOTB hotfolder. Also you can write custom code in your uploading process .BTW , to be honest my last sentence is not so meaningful . Because need to know your hotfolder xml context to give more hints ..

Answer (score 0):

**Hot-folder** ingests a file in a series of steps specified by the *beans* in the `hot-folder-spring.xml`.
Add *loggers* in each of the bean, 
eg- `batchFilesHeader`,
 `batchExternalTaxConverterMapping`

Then you can see the status in the console logs.